# Type mismatch with abstract types

Tags: scala, abstract-type

I'm using abstract types and having problems getting Scala compiler to unify two types that should be the same. These are my definitions:

```
trait Chromosome {
  type Gene

  val size : Int

  def apply(idx : Int) : Gene

  def update(idx : Int, g : Gene)

  def indices = Range(0, size-1)
}


trait Individual {
  type Fitness
  implicit protected val ord: Ordered[Fitness] = implicitly[Ordered[Fitness]]

  val chromosome : Chromosome

  def size : Int = chromosome.size

  def apply(idx : Int) : chromosome.Gene = chromosome.apply(idx)
  def update(idx : Int, g : chromosome.Gene ) = chromosome.update(idx, g)

  protected var _fitness : Fitness = _
  def fitness : Fitness = _fitness
  def fitness_=(f : Fitness):Unit = _fitness = f
}


case class ArrayChromosome(size : Int) extends Chromosome {
  implicit protected val tag : ClassTag[Gene] = implicitly[ClassTag[Gene]]

  protected val xs : Array[Gene] = new Array[Gene](size)

  def apply(idx : Int) = xs(idx)

  def update(idx : Int, g : Gene) = xs(idx) = g
}


abstract class ArrayIndividual(size : Int) extends Individual {
  val chromosome  = ArrayChromosome(size)
}


class MyIndividual(size : Int) extends ArrayIndividual(size) {
  type Gene = Int
  type Fitness = Double
}


object Test extends App {
  val i1 = new MyIndividual(10)

  i1.fitness = 10.5
  i1.chromosome(0) = 6
  print(i1)
}
```

Namely, the problem is in this line:

```
i1.chromosome(0) = 6
```

and the type error is:

```
Error:(75, 22) type mismatch;
 found   : Int(6)
 required: abstractTypes.Test.i1.chromosome.Gene
  i1.chromosome(0) = 6
```

It seems that the compiler is unable to unify `i1.chromosome.Gene` with `Int`.

I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to help the compiler unify both types?
2. Let me now assume that I have removed the offending line and that I have defined properly `toString` for `Individual`s. Why do I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException` when running `Test`. It seems that the error is related to `Gene` `ClassTag`, but I'm not sure.

**Code of response** to @som-snytt:

```
abstract class ArrayIndividual(size : Int) extends Individual {
  type Gene
  implicit protected def tag2: ClassTag[Gene]

  val chromosome  = new ArrayChromosome(size) {
    type Gene = ArrayIndividual#Gene
    protected val tag : ClassTag[Gene] = tag2
  }
}

class MyIndividual(size : Int) extends ArrayIndividual(size) {
  type Fitness = Double
  type Gene = Int
  implicit protected val tag2 : ClassTag[Gene] = implicitly[ClassTag[Gene]]

  override def toString = s"${super.toString} $chromosome"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Scala, types are not globally scoped. You have written `Gene` as a member of the type `Chromosome`, but you're trying to define it in a subclass of `Individual` (which "has a" `Chromosome`, not "is a" `Chromosome`).

You can choose where to declare and define it, but it must be in the same hierarchy, just as when you override a term member such as a method.

An `individual.Gene` has nothing to do with a `chromosome.Gene` in your example.

Move the type definition where you need it for the ClassTag anyway:

```
case class ArrayChromosome(size : Int) extends Chromosome {
  type Gene = Int
  implicit protected val tag : ClassTag[Gene] = implicitly[ClassTag[Gene]]
```

D'oh, I just noticed you're defining your implicit recursively. The implicitly on the RHS uses the implicit you're defining. So don't do that. The compiler summons the implicit on its own.

But if you did need to supply an implicit tag in a superclass which didn't fix the aliased type, you could have an abstract method to supply a class tag that would be implemented in a concrete class.

For example, letting an `Individual` subclass specify the concrete `Chromosome`:

```
abstract class ArrayChromosome(val size : Int) extends Chromosome {
  //type Gene = Int
  //implicit protected val tag : ClassTag[Gene] = implicitly[ClassTag[Gene]]
  implicit protected def tag: ClassTag[Gene]

  protected lazy val xs : Array[Gene] = new Array[Gene](size)

  def apply(idx : Int) = xs(idx)

  def update(idx : Int, g : Gene) = xs(idx) = g
}


abstract class ArrayIndividual(size : Int) extends Individual {
  //val chromosome  = ArrayChromosome(size)
  val chromosome  = new ArrayChromosome(size) {
    type Gene = Int
    protected val tag = implicitly[ClassTag[Gene]]
  }
}


class MyIndividual(size : Int) extends ArrayIndividual(size) {
  type Fitness = Double

  override def toString = s"${super.toString} $chromosome"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but type Gene should be abstract in class ArrayChromosome and only get defined later in subclasses extending this one. I guess I could add a type parameter, but is it possible to solve the unification problem without such parameter?

Comment: That's what I meant by the comment about tag. I'll add code example.

Comment: Note the lazy val.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but the problem is that `Gene` in class `ArrayIndividual` should be abstract, and should only get instantiated later in a subclass, such as `MyIndividual`. I have tried to do that with the code that I have added at the end of my question above, where I try to unify abstract type `Gene` in class `ArrayIndividual` with the type of the `Gene`used in the `chormosome` but this still fails with an error. Seems that Scala compiler is unable to unify both types, even after providing that equality. Do you know how to fix this problem?

Comment: You are introducing the name `Gene` in unrelated scopes. The two usages are apples and oranges. I hope my edit helps.

Comment: Thanks again. I understand that I'm using composition and not inheritance, but, in the code at the end of my question (not in the original one), how is it that this equality `type Gene = ArrayIndividual#Gene` does not unify both `Gene`s?